# Import Error when importing ValueError Exception

Tags: python

I was trying this

```
from exceptions import ValueError
```

but got an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'
```

any solutions??

Comment: `ValueError` is a built-in. There is no need (or option...) to import it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to import `ValueError`. It's a built-in so you can always `raise ValueError()`.

Comment: thanks **tdy** and **olirwin**, so should I comment the line?

Comment: yes, you can just comment/delete that line

Comment: just for the record, ValueError is being imported automatically by some plugins in vscode

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to import Exceptions. You can just use them as such

```py
raise ValueError(text)
```